# URL management in CI 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making user friendly url for my website .

I have done url management , its working fine , but I need to reduce my codes .

I am posting my code , can anyone suggest me?

```html
$route['admin/calender_timetable/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = 'admin/admin/calender_timetable/$1';

$route['admin/single_teacher_details/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = 'admin/admin/single_teacher_details/$1';
```

I managed the above url in this way .

Is there any way so that I can do it using one line router management .

Thank you  in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$route['admin/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = 'admin/admin/$1/$2';
```

`$1` matches with `[a-zA-Z_]+` regular expression and `$2` is matches with `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` regular expression.

Learn more about regular expression here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @sradha glad to help you.enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above is totally correct, mind using handy helpers from the framework as CodeIgniter already provides a wide range if them;

```
$route['admin/(:alpha)/(:num)'] = 'admin/admin/$1/$2';
```

Which will result in the exact same and might eases readability when using it on many routes.